# Bootstrap Navbar items and logo not showing on mobile screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used Bootstrap navbar in my website with the following design. It works perfectly but the items including the social links and logo not shown in mobile devices.

Should I go and add `@media(min-max width)` with every classes and id or is there any other simple way which I changed it by mistake maybe

```css
.navbar-header.col {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar {
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.nav-link img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: -8px 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.navbar ul.nav li a:hover,
.navbar ul.nav li a:focus {
  color: #f08373 !important;
}

.navbar ul.nav li.active a,
.navbar ul.nav li.active a:hover,
.navbar ul.nav li.active a:focus {
  color: #eb5844 !important;
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar .nav-item i {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar .nav-item.open>a {
  background: none !important;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 23px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-fixed-top">
  <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center">
    <div class="navbar-header d-flex col">
      <a id="logo" href="index.html"><img src="./img/logo1.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item" style="right: 100px;">
        <a href="tel:000000" style="color: #514eec;"></i>
          000000</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" style="right: 80px;">
        <a href="tel:000000" style="color: #514eec;"></i>
          0000000</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" style="color: #514eec;" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #514eec;" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #514eec;" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You need to add a mobile toggle button (like a hamburger menu icon) to toggle it open, because the navbar is collapsed in mobile views by default. Read the docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-default)... _"They begin collapsed (and are toggleable) in mobile views and become horizontal as the available viewport width increases."_

Comment: Why you use bootstrap 3 cdn and Bootstrap 4 class?

Comment: Sorry First I used 4 and then I changed to 3 where I forgot to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

You did wrong. You use **Bootstrap@4** `navbar` HTML code and your cdn is **Bootstrap@3** it will not work.

Bootstrap@4 navbar [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/) and Bootstrap@4 [CDN](https://getbootstrap.com)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-header.col {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar {
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.nav-link img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  margin: -8px 0;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.navbar ul.nav li a:hover,
.navbar ul.nav li a:focus {
  color: #f08373 !important;
}

.navbar ul.nav li.active a,
.navbar ul.nav li.active a:hover,
.navbar ul.nav li.active a:focus {
  color: #eb5844 !important;
  background: transparent !important;
}

.navbar .nav-item i {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.navbar .nav-item.open>a {
  background: none !important;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav>li>a {
    padding-top: 23px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand-lg navbar-light navbar-fixed-top">
  <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <!-- Remove collapse and navbar-collapse here -->
  <div id="navbarCollapse" class=" justify-content-center">
    <div class="navbar-header d-flex col">
      <a id="logo" href="index.html"><img src="./img/logo1.png" alt=""> YOUR LOGO</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ml-auto">
      <!-- Consider to use margin-right instead of right -->
      <li class="nav-item" style="margin-right: 10px;">
        <a href="tel:000000" style="color: #514eec;"></i>
          000000</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" style="margin-right: 10px;">
        <a href="tel:000000" style="color: #514eec;"></i>
          0000000</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" style="color: #514eec;" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #514eec;" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank" style="color: #514eec;" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```